# node errors when running gulp del task

Tags: node.js, gulp, delete-file

I cannot figure out why I am getting a node `ENOENT` error, when running a simple task to clean out my vendor files.

My gulp task looks like this

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');

module.exports = function(opt){
    gulp.task('clean:vendor', function(cb){
        return del(['src/vendor/'],cb)
    });
}
```

When I run the command `gulp clean:vendor` against a file structure that looks like this:

```
gulpfile.js
src/vendor/js
src/vendor/css
```

I get this error from node, and I cannot figure out how to catch or fix.

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/aycollin/seed/src/vendor/js/bootstrap.js'
```

Comment: The task runs fine for me on OSX Yosemite using gulp 3.8.x. Can you give some more information on your environment? E.g. OS/Versions of node and gulp?

Comment: Nevermind I'm killing that repo I have something better that's working now, thanks for trying it out.